# Problem with remapped key when changing between languages

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

I've remapped a certain key (<kbd>`</kbd> to <kbd>w</kbd>) with this way:

> xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = w"

I use Greek language, not only English and I change between languages with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. When I turn the keyboard layout to Greek it should output a greek character that is assigned to w key at greek keyboards (the character ς). It continues to output w when I turn the keyboard to Greek. The name that is given to this greek character (when I press w/ς key after xev at the terminal with the language turned to Greek) is Greek_finalsmallsigma

Temporarily I did the following in order to output the greek character by pressing Shift

> xmodmap -e "keycode 49 = w Greek_finalsmallsigma"

Is there a way to change the output of that key when I change between Greek and English with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> ?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), *or* press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for a run-command textbox. Type:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gr
```

Find the line starting with:

```
key <AD02>
```

and replace it with:

```
key <AD02> { [ Greek_finalsmallsigma,    Greek_SIGMA ] }; // ς Σ
```

Then save the file and restart your computer.